How to pass data from ajax sucess to other method in javascript?
Sorry, I am new to javascript and cannot understand how to pass the needed data.
Here is my ajax call:
$(document).ready(function (){
    loadSkiResortData();
});

function loadSkiResortData(){
    $.ajax({
       method: 'GET',
       url: '/admin/sknowed/loadSkiResortData',
       success: function(response){
           console.log(typeof response.weatherData);
           const obj = JSON.parse(response.weatherData);
           console.log(obj.hourly.temperature_2m);
           console.log(obj.hourly.time);
       }
    });
}

The above returns the "temperature" (obj.hourly.temperature_2m) and the data/time (obj.hourly.time).  The temperature and date/time need to be passed to chart.js as follows;
const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');

new Chart(ctx, 

{
    type: 'line',
    data: 
        {
            labels: // I want to replace this array with obj.hourly.time
                [
                    'Red', 
                    'Blue', 
                    'Yellow', 
                    'Green', 
                    'Purple', 
                    'Orange'
                ],
            datasets: 
                [
                    {
                        label: 'My chart label',
                        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3], // I want to replace this array with obj.hourly.temperature_2m
                        borderWidth: 1
                    }
                ]
        },
}

I want to make the labels array equal to I want to obj.hourly.time and the data array equal to obj.hourly.temperature_2m.
Sorry but I would appreciate any pointers please.

However if i had a say in things, just. dont. use. ajax. fetch is built in, fast, and just amazing for asynchronous and synchronous operations. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

you're already passing the data to console.log and JSON.parse - so, technically, you already know how to pass data from ajax success to another method in javascript - there's no difference between "built-in" methods and methods you write

@Hermanboxcar - how is fetch "fast and amazing" for "synchronous things" - since fetch is asynchronous?

@JaromandaX you can use it as an await which is basically structured as synchronous except your browser is happy (sorry my brain is dead right now)

@Hermanboxcar - I get it! yes, you can do that with jquery ajax too, since it returns a promise :p But I agree, jQuery.ajax is largely redundant

You might not need jQuery
